# Mudar ícone APP depois de instalado - IONIC

Tags: ionic

Estou desenvolvendo um APP em ionic 1.x e gostaria de saber se é possível alterar o ícone do APP depois que instalado no celular do usuário.

Vi algumas soluções mas todas em código nativo de seus aparelhos.

Alguém possui esse conhecimento?

Comment: Se eu intendi, é só colocar o novo ícone no app, gerar a apk e mandar para o cliente reinstalar.

Comment: Olá @leopiazzoli, no caso seria mudar o ícone DEPOIS que instalado, isto é, alterar o ícone dinamicamente pelo APP, via programação. Por exemplo: tem um APP de calendário que o ícone fica com o dia corrente nas telas do launcher.

Comment: Agora intendi. Não sei dizer como fazer ainda porque nunca precisei, mas para ter melhores respostas aconselho colocar este exemplo que vc me citou e se possível imagens :)

Answer (score 3):

As soluções de código nativo são válidas, você pode importar o projeto que você está trabalhando (ionic) no android studio e fazer a alteração dos ícones e gerar no novo .apk. Como importar esse projeto ?

1. Quando você executa o comando 'ionic platform add android' o ionic irá criar uma pasta com um projeto que pode ser importado no android studio na pasta raiz do seu projeto dentro de \platforms\android (quando for importar com o android studio ele irá identificar como um projeto android).
2. Após importado ele você deverá alterar as imagens que estão localizadas dentro da pasta res/drawable (ao alterar as imagens observe as extensões e tamanhos) para manter um padrão você deve manter os atuais.

Answer (score 0):

Desde iOS **10.3+** isso é possível (desde 2017), mas para aplicativos Cordova (como o Ionic) é que vai depender de um plugin específico.

Você pode experimentar este plug-in (apenas iOS, não Android) [`cordova-plugin-app-icon-changer`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-app-icon-changer)

Instale usando:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-app-icon-changer
```

Para verificar o suporte:

```
AppIconChanger.isSupported(function(supported) {
    if (supported) {
          ...
    } else {
          ...
    }
});
```

Para ícone de mudança:

```
AppIconChanger.changeIcon({
    iconName: "<coloque o nome do icone aqui>",
    suppressUserNotification: true
}, function() {
     // Changed...
}, function(err) {
     // If failed ...
});
```

Para mais plugins, veja: https://cordova.apache.org/plugins/?q=icon

> **Nota:** se algo for desejado, você pode implementar seu próprio plug-in (ou se quiser criar um aplicativo nativo) usando
> [**`setAlternateIconName(_:completionHandler:)`**](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/2806818-setalternateiconname)
>
> É importante verificar se a troca é suportada usando
> [`supportsAlternateIcons`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/2806815-supportsalternateicons)

Após colocar as imagens no `assets` acesse `Info.plist` ([`CFBundleIcons`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/cfbundleicons)) adicione `CFBundleAlternateIcons` com os itens correspondentes às imagens, conforme no exemplo:

```
▼ CFBundleIcons
  ▼ CFBundleAlternateIcons
    ▼ <coloque o nome do icone aqui>
      ▶ CFBundleIconFiles
```

Se você precisar de suporte para iPad, a estrutura deve ser semelhante a:

```
▼ CFBundleIcons
  ▼ CFBundleAlternateIcons
    ▼ <coloque o nome do icone aqui>
      ▶ CFBundleIconFiles
▼ CFBundleIcons~ipad
  ▼ CFBundleAlternateIcons
    ▼ <coloque o nome do icone aqui>
      ▶ CFBundleIconFiles
```

Exemplo de imagem para projetos Cordova (por exemplo, Ionic)

> [image: info.plist]

### Plug-ins Android Cordova

Até agora não encontrei plug-ins existentes que façam isso para o Android, mas de acordo com esta resposta [*How to change an application icon programmatically in Android?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1103027/1518921) (não consegui testar as respostas no momento), aparentemente é possível alterar o ícone.